# How to have the main form listen out for a button click in a control

Tags: c#, winforms

The app I am building kind of functions a bit like a website in that I have a main content area and a load of buttons along the side which then displays different content in the main content area.

The main content area I have is made up of a blank panel (pnlMainContent) which is then populated with a User Control when a button/tab is clicked.

The first User Control I have put in includes another button which should then populate the main content Panel with a different User Control.

How do I get the main form to listen out for the button click within the User Control so I can then clear the panel and populate it with another User Control?

As it stands, I can't see pnlMainContent from within the User Control.

Comment: How do you add your UserControl to your pnlMainContent? The Panel should appear as the Parent property inside the UserControl

Comment: @Steve - So have I done it the wrong way round?

The code to populate the panel is as follows:

private void btnMemberOverview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ctrlMemberOverview memberOverview = new ctrlMemberOverview();
            pnlMainContent.Controls.Add(memberOverview);
        }

Comment: Okay, so your user control should raise a custom event which could just be a passthrough for the button. That's the correct way of bubbling events up.

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi - Okay so i'm still pretty new to coding. Can you recommend an article which can help me achieve this?

Comment: You need to learn about events and delegate. You need to create custom event for the user control which will be triggered when button on the user control is clicked. When you add user control to the form you need to attach the event of the control to a event handler method in the Form. And in that event handler you write code of loading another user control. That what when you click on the button in the first user control it will execute code in the form and load another user control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your UserControl you need to create a custom event.  This is triggered when you perform your action in the user control.
Then the main form subscribes to this and is informed every time this action occurs.

Your user control

```
//Declare a delegate and Event.  Here called StatusUpdate
public delegate void StatusUpdateHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event StatusUpdateHandler OnUpdateStatus;

//When button is clicked, this is trigged
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //In here, you now trigger your custom event
    UpdateStatus(); 
}


private void UpdateStatus()
{
     //Create arguments.  You should also have custom one, or else return EventArgs.Empty();
     EventArgs args = new EventArgs();

     //Call any listeners
     OnUpdateStatus?.Invoke(this, args);

}
```

Then in your main form subscribe to this event

```
yourUserControl.OnUpdateStatus += customControl_OnUpdateStatus;
...

private void customControl_OnUpdateStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ///Handle your event here        
}
```

Comment: Excellent, you are a star!